# Django defining __str__ for nested foreign key

Tags: django

Using a nested model like this:

```
class Gov(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class State(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Gov)
    abbreviation = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.parent.name

class State_Park(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(State)
    park_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

How would I set `__str__` for class `State_Park` to be `name` in `class Gov`?

I tried:

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.parent.parent.name
```

which did not work.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\ccsv\Envs\wenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 229, in __repr__
    return '<%s %r>' % (self.__class__.__name__, data)
  File "C:\Users\ccsv\Envs\wenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 589, in __repr__
    u = six.text_type(self)
  File "C:\Users\ccsv\Desktop\wenv\mysite\stats\models.py", line 89, in __str__
    return self.parent.parent.name()
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: what do you mean does not work?

Comment: You have tried to set a `related_name` param to your ForeignKey column?

Comment: @BearBrown that gave TypeError: String is not callable

Comment: No, it would not give that message. If you're seeing an error, post it along with the full traceback.

Comment: @Abe please don't make irrelevant points.

Comment: @Abe Yes I tried that it gave me errors when I tried makemigrations.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Abe's point is actually relevant because it might be a better way define ForeignKey Objects.

Comment: No, Abe's point is irrelevant because you are accessing the forward relationships in each case, so related_name has nothing to do with it. However you do still need to post the full error and traceback.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Don't be too harsh, let people help in a way they can. I know `related_name` is not connected to OP issue at-least @Abe is trying to figure out in his own way.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Ok I posted the full traceback the problem is that it is returning an object instead of a string. This is when I accessed the query through the Django shell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 File "C:\Users\ccsv\Desktop\wenv\mysite\stats\models.py", line 89, in __str__
return self.parent.parent.name()
```

Based on the error log, I think you should remove the parenthesis at the end of your line.

```
    def __str__(self):
        return self.parent.parent.name
```

Comment: Dang I hate it when I post some small mistake on Stack that I did not see.

Answer (score 4):

in your real code is

```
return self.parent.parent.name()
```

just remove brackets

```
return self.parent.parent.name
#                            ^^^
```